# GoogleMap is streched out instead of resized after sibling animation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation

Here's what I want to achieve.

When I click a `FAB` button, a menu will toogle display at the bottom of the screen.

When the menu is opened/closed, the map has to be resized so there is no blank space when the menu is animated.

My problem is that when I animate the map's container (ViewPager), the container animates as expected but the map is streched out instead of resizing to the proper dimensions.

I have a ViewPager with a TabLayout that display a fragment per page:

- page 1 (google map)
- page 2,3 etc..

Here's my toggle menu code:

```
    public void animateFAB(FABStates state) {
        if (state.equals(FABStates.show)) {
            isFABOpen = true;

            viewPager.animate()
                    .scaleY(1f)
                    .setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR)
                    .setDuration(500);

            mapUtilsContainer.animate().scaleY(1f)
                                .setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR)
                                .setDuration(500);

            MapView mapV = mapFragment.getMapView();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lps = mapV.getLayoutParams();
            lps.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            mapV.requestLayout();

//            for (int v = 0; v < FABMenu.length; v++) {
//                FABMenu[v].animate().translationX(0).setStartDelay(90 * v);
//            }
        } else {
            isFABOpen = false;
            mapUtilsContainer.setPivotY(mapUtilsContainer.getMeasuredHeight());
            mapUtilsContainer.setPivotX(0);

            viewPager.animate()
                    .scaleY(1.5f)
                    .setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR)
                    .setDuration(500);
            mapUtilsContainer.animate()
                    .scaleY(0f)
                    .setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR)
                    .setDuration(500);
            MapView mapV = mapFragment.getMapView();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lps = mapV.getLayoutParams();
            lps.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            mapV.requestLayout();

//            for (int v = 0; v < FABMenu.length; v++) {
//                FABMenu[v].animate().translationX(10000).setStartDelay(90 * v);
//            }
        }
    }
```

### Option 2

```
    public void animateFAB(FABStates state) {
        if (state.equals(FABStates.show)) {
            isFABOpen = true;

            ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
            va.setDuration(500);
            va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    mapUtilsContainer.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                    mapUtilsContainer.requestLayout();
                }
            });
            va.start();

            View v = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
            v.requestLayout();

//            for (int v = 0; v < FABMenu.length; v++) {
//                FABMenu[v].animate().translationX(0).setStartDelay(90 * v);
//            }
        } else {
            isFABOpen = false;

            ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            va.setDuration(500);
            va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    mapUtilsContainer.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                    mapUtilsContainer.requestLayout();
                }
            });
            va.start();

            View v = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
            v.requestLayout();

//            for (int v = 0; v < FABMenu.length; v++) {
//                FABMenu[v].animate().translationX(10000).setStartDelay(90 * v);
//            }
        }
    }
```

Is the `WRAP_CONTENT` used wrongfully here?

Comment: I'm sure there's a better solution to the animation and how to handle map resizing, this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of `scale()`. As I have just tested it works fine if you set the height in pixels. Try `ValueAnimator` to animate height. This way you should take record of opened/closed height of map beforehand. Example:

```
ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(oldHeight, newHeight);
va.setDuration(500);
va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        v.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
        v.requestLayout();
    }
});
```

Instead of `WRAP_CONTENT` assign initial height while it is open and use it to reopen:

```
public void animateFAB(FABStates state) {
    if (state.equals(FABStates.show)) {
        isFABOpen = true;
        initialHeight = mapUtilsContainer.getLayoutParams().height; 
        ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialHeight, 0);
        ...
    } else {
        isFABOpen = false;
        ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, initialHeight);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This animation has a weird flicker. It occupies the entire screen and then snaps to it's position. I'll update the code

Comment: @estebanrincon edited my answer. Try without `WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: Hey, I've already tried with `mapUtilsContainer.getLayoutParams().height;` but this always returned 0.  I was going to try your initial answer but haven't had the time. Could you please leave the first answer as well?

Comment: My first answer was the first code block, I just added the second block (instead of wrap content). I just don't get what your layout looks like. Do you want your mapView take the place of your mapUtilsContainer? FAB button opens menuUtils and closes map with your first click?